# Tinkerpop Gremlin - Inconsistent results using math() within match()

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm quite new to gremlin and I've been getting inconsistent results using `math()` within a `match()` step that I can't figure out.

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()

john = g.addV('person').property('name', 'John').next()
sam = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Sam').next()

g.V(john).addE('knows').to(sam).property('weight', 18).next()
g.V(sam).addE('knows').to(john).property('weight', 3).next()
```

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('person').
  match(
    __.as('vert_a').outE('knows').as('edge_a'),
    __.as('vert_a').inE('knows').as('edge_b'),
    __.as('edge_b').math('edge_a + edge_b').by('weight').as('weight_sum')
  ).select('vert_a', 'weight_sum').
    by('name').
    by()
```

The above query will throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the second result:

```
==>[vert_a:John,weight_sum:21.0]
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I assume this is an issue with the way I'm creating this graph as the query runs fine on the modern graph. There's no issues that I can see traversing the graph outside of this `match()` step. Both `__.as('edge_a').math('edge_a + 10').by('weight')` and `__.as('edge_b').math('edge_b + 10').by('weight')` both work fine without throwing exceptions, which confuses me even more. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this exception, and how I can reliably do maths referencing variables within a `match()` step? Also, does anyone know the reason this returns the first result fine, but fails on the second?

Thanks.

Edit:
I just want to clarify that the above example is an arbitrary simplified example of an issue I'm facing in another dataset, and not an actual query I'm looking for an alternative solution to. So I'm aiming to understand how `math()` works within `match()` and if it really is limited to only using one named variable at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use a `match` step here. I think all you need is this:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel('person').
......2>   project('name','sum').
......3>     by('name').
......4>     by(bothE('knows').values('weight').sum())   

==>[name:John,sum:21]
==>[name:Sam,sum:21]
```

If you wanted to keep using `match` then the `math` step needs to be done outside the `match` something like this. In general I find use of `match` can be avoided however.

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel('person').
......2>   match(
......3>     __.as('vert_a').outE('knows').as('edge_a'),
......4>     __.as('vert_a').inE('knows').as('edge_b')
......5>   ).project('vert_a', 'weight_sum').
......6>       by(select('vert_a').values('name')).
......7>       by(math('edge_a + edge_b').by('weight') )  

==>[vert_a:John,weight_sum:21.0]
==>[vert_a:Sam,weight_sum:21.0]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. The example above is just arbitrarily demonstrating of the issue without context. The query I'm building matches specific edges, does math on the weights, filters them accordingly and returns the originating vertice, the destination vertice, and the calculation. I can achieve the result with a combination of `group()`, `project()` and `union()`, however it is gets very messy maintaining variables (eg.`'vert_a'`) throughout, and some steps like `group()` slow down the query a lot.

Comment: With `match()` the whole query is clear and performant except when it *sometimes* decides to throw exceptions, even in the very simple example above. So I really hope for a resolution within `match()` before maybe (likely?) resulting to leaving the match() early for the remainder of the query.